# Other Flex IDEs?

Tags: visual-studio, apache-flex, ide, flexbuilder

I am an Adobe Flex developer and I am sick of Eclipse. Is there an alternative (free) IDE for Flex? I am aware of Tofino, but I can't get that to work on my MSVS Express editions, and I don't want to buy the whole thing. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't concerned with a visual designer, there is also [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org).

Answer (score 1):

The current version of [IntelliJIDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) 8.1.x supports Flex which is pretty nice (along with debugger for Flex).  However, there are some limitations with it but with the [next version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/index.html) it has better Flex'ing support including AIR, FlexUNIT, etc...

I personally only used IDEA a couple of time for Flex projects, I prefer [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) for Ruby and Flex and use FlexBuilder for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Tofino not work on VS Express Edition, but is an alternative to Eclipse Flex. You don't have much more.

Answer (score 0):

There is Amesthst which is a flex development that runs in Visual Studio. I did not have the best luck in using it, or stuck with eclipse as that was the tool used by the rest of my group.

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Adobe-Flex-Development-in-Visual

Answer (score 0):

Amethyst runs in the free VS Shell Edition. We released a new beta this week with a visual designer:

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Amethyst-Beta-6-Adobe-Flex-Visual

Download here:

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Download-Amethyst-Adobe-Flex-IDE

If you need the VS Shell download the All-in-One installer for our Ruby On Rails IDE. This includes VS Shell and you can install Amethyst into that:

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/spip?page=download

best wishes

Huw